# Trying to randomly pick numbers in c# with an action

Tags: c#, random, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

Sorry for any miswording of anything here I am not a native english speaker I have been trying to randomly pick a number between 1 - 6 in c# and for whatever reason it says System.Func`1[System.Int32] every time I try to print it out
(i know usually this is done in main but this is my homework and I was ordered not to put it in main)

```
namespace ConsoleApp9
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static Random random = new Random();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(GetDice);
        }

        public static int GetDice()
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            int dice = random.Next(1, 100);
            return dice;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(GetDice());`

Comment: Note I just saw that I did  Random random = new Random(); twice it does not fix putting it once

Comment: Note, that `Console.WriteLine(GetDice);` is to print out `GetDice` method itself (e.g. its address) when `Console.WriteLine(GetDice());` is to *call* `GetDice()` and print out its returned value.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't randomly pick language tags. There is no C code involved. Also the specific version of C# doesn't seem relevant. Finally, please spent a few seconds when posting code to make it more readable. Loads of empty lines do not add any value and just make it harder to see the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

To provide some more information: `GetDice` Is called a "method group", i.e. one or more methods in a class with the same name, but different parameters. In this case this converted to a delegate and that is converted to a string. This is where your `System.Func[System.Int32]` comes from, it says that it is a function with no arguments that returns int. I.e. the signature of the GetDice method.

What you want to do is *call the method*, i.e. `GetDice()`

```
 Console.WriteLine(GetDice());
```

Another common error when forgetting the parentheses is `cannot convert from 'method group' to <type>`, i.e. it failed to do the conversion. This will also depend on the .net/c# version, some versions will generate the error, some will succeed but will not do what you expect it to.

You might also want to consider turning on "treat warnings as errors". I would *expect* your code to at least give a warning, since it is a fairly easy mistake to make. But I'm not using the same .net version as you, so I'm not sure exactly what warnings are generated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get a value between 1 and 6 your GetDice() method should be like this:

```
public static int GetDice()
{
    Random random = new Random();
    int dice = random.Next(1, 7);
    return dice;
}
```

and you call it in Main like this

```
Console.WriteLine(GetDice());
```